# Error al usar ng-model en un elemento button

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Estoy intentando colocar en un `ng-model` el valor que tenga en la tabla en la inserto tareas, pero me aparece el siguiente error:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{tarea.fila}}] starting at [{tarea.fila}}]
```

Los valores que guardo son los siguientes:

```
objetoTarea = [{
  fila: 1,
  texto: "Examen de calculo",
  fecha: "12-05-2016"
}];
```

#### calendarioestu.html

```
<ul class="list">

        <li class="item item-divider">
            Tareas
        </li>

        <li class="item item-button-right" ng-repeat="tarea in nueva.tareasEstu">
            <h3 class="title">{{tarea.texto}}</h3>
            <button class="button button-clear button-balanced" ng-model="{{tarea.fila}}" ng-click="eliminarTareas()">
                <i class="icon ion-ios-close-empty"></i>
            </button>
        </li>

    </ul>
```

El texto lo muestra sin problema alguno, pero el `ng-model` que esta allí, lo puse ya que ni siquiera el editor lo permite poner allí y no se por que.

#### calendarioestu.js

```
$scope.eliminarTareas = function() {

    var fila_Tarea;

    fila_Tarea = $scope.nueva.fila;
    console.log(fila_Tarea);
}
```

El código anterior es con la finalidad de obtener dicho valor en el `ng-model`, pero al no poder usarlo, no se como hacer entonces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como puedes ver en la [documentación](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) de AngularJs, el uso de la directiva `ng-model` está restringido a los elementos de tipo `input`, `textarea` y `select`.

Además en esta directiva se establece un valor de texto haciendo referencia a la propiedad del scope a la que quieres enlazar y no una expresión.

No sé lo que quieres hacer exactamente , pero si lo que pretendes es eliminar una tarea identificada por la propiedad `fila` bastaría con pasarla como parámetro al método 'eliminarTareas`

Tu vista quedaría de esta manera:

```
<ul class="list">

    <li class="item item-divider">
        Tareas
    </li>

    <li class="item item-button-right" ng-repeat="tarea in nueva.tareasEstu">
        <h3 class="title">{{tarea.texto}}</h3>
        <button class="button button-clear button-balanced" ng-click="eliminarTareas(tarea.fila)">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-close-empty"></i>
        </button>
    </li´
</ul>
```

Y este sería el método recibiendo como parámetro la fila a eliminar

```
$scope.eliminarTareas = function(fila_tarea) {

    console.log(fila_Tarea);
}
```

Comment: Voy a probar y ya mismo te digo que tal me fue

Comment: Si funciono, gracias

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales no hay de que. Por cierto, estaría bien que aceptaras la respuesta, si consideras que es correcta. Saludos

Comment: se me había pasado, disculpa ya la puse